# QDomDocument: setContent error with XML tag

Tags: xml, qt, qxmlstreamreader, qdomdocument

I am trying to set my XML file to QDomDocument using setContent and it returns an error.

My XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <Tag1>
        <Attribute1>5</Attribute1>
        <Attribute2>5</Attribute2>
    </Tag1>
    <Settings\it.server.com>
        <Attribute1>1</Attribute1>
    </Settings\it.server.com>
</root>
```

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
QFile file(fileName);

if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
    QDomDocument domDocument;

    QString errorStr;
    int errorLine;
    int errorColumn;

    if (!domDocument.setContent(&file, false, &errorStr, &errorLine, &errorColumn))
        qDebug() << errorStr << errorLine << errorColumn;
}
```

The error message I am getting when I run is the following:

> error: error occurred while parsing element 7 11

Where row = 7 and column = 11.

Now I'm pretty sure it is probably because of the "\" or "." character in the tag **(Settings\it.server.com)** that could be causing it to fail. The XML can't be changed because it is from an external source. My question is there anyway around this using QDomDocument?

I have looked into QXmlStreamReader and Writer but I haven't figured out how to update attributes. QDomDocument has better facilities for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML parser accepts letter, digits, periods, hyphens, etc. You have to remove illegal characters before parsing:

```
QFile f(filename);
if (!f.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text)) return;

QTextStream in(&f);
QString content = in.readAll(); // Get the content

content.replace("\\", "_"); // Remove all '\' char

if (!domDocument.setContent(content, false, &errorStr, &errorLine, &errorColumn))
        qDebug() << errorStr << errorLine << errorColumn;
```

If your Xml file are huge, you also can create your own `QXmlInputSource` subclass and replace the illegal characters during the reading (see [QXmlInputSource::next()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxmlinputsource.html#next))